# Pass Session Variable to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm tring to pass a session variable to javascript but not have success.
Searching stackoverflow i have found this discussion:
[Passing Session variables to javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363432/passing-session-variables-to-javascript)

in my custom.js i have on header

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

.. /// js code

strActionPage = CurrentPath + "upload_file.php?ation=store&session_user_id=<?php echo $_SESSION['session_user_id']; ?>   "; //the ActionPage's file path
```

but i cant get session variable from upload_file.php page

where do I wrong?

Tks to all

Comment: have you debug it? using chrome inspector or firebug?

Comment: I do not know chrome inspector: (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait, you're using PHP on a JavaScript file (that's what your OP says)? Not gonna work. You're going to have to pass it to a JavaScript function as a parameter like so:

```
<?php
session_start();

// HTML and stuff

<script type="text/javascript" src="custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
passSession("<? echo $_SESSION['session_user_id']; ?>");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without knowing more about your particular error, but I did notice what seems like a typo in the code you posted:

```
strActionPage = CurrentPath + "upload_file.php?ation=store&session_user_id=<?php echo $_SESSION['session_user_id']; ?>   "; //the ActionPage's file path
```

You have `ation-store` -- did you mean to write `action=store`?

Comment: is a typo because I am translating into English. but is not this. Tks for your reply.

Comment: in that case, can you edit your OP to give more information about the error and any additional relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I might do.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

    var user_id=<?php echo $_SESSION['session_user_id']; ?>;

    strActionPage = CurrentPath + "upload_file.php?action=store&session_user_id="+user_id;  

    </script>
```

There is also a possible  mistake. You are using "ation" . Should that be 'action'?